# what does it mean by "triple their share of the population"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Considerable improvement in the treatment of HIV has also decreased premature deaths for black men, who were hammered by the epidemic. An estimated 42% of the 1.1m Americans living with HIV today are black, **triple their share of the population.** At the peak of the epidemic, around 1994, the virus was killing blacks at an age-adjusted rate of nearly 60 per 100,000-or three times the rate at which opioid overdoses killed whites in 2017.

Is the subject of "triple their share of the population" black people?
and 42% is the result of being "tripled"? 
and what does "the population" in their share of the population refer to? Is it Americans as a whole?

Can anyone help me with this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

The subject is "An estimated 42%" which is triple the share of the American population (i.e., the percentage of the population) that is black. **Share** means **percentage**.

The percentage of the American population that is black is 14%, but the percentage of Americans living with HIV who are black is triple that at 42%. The concept overall is that black Americans are disproportionately overrepresented in the HIV population.

Comment: How can black living with HIV(42) be bigger than whole black people in America(14%)??

Comment: @dbwlsld It's the black percentage of the American HIV population (42% of 1.1 million) compared to the black percentage of the American population (14% of 300 million, or whatever the total American population is at the moment).

Comment: @dbwlsld This says that 14% of people living in America are black (roughly 3 out of 20 people). But 41% of people living in America *with AIDS* are black (roughly 8 out of 20 people). There is more to the AIDS statistic than you would expect from just a proportional representation (3 out of 20) of citizenship. Everything being equal, the proportions should be the same—but they aren't.